# How to iterate over a list of floats in python

Tags: python

I am trying to iterate over a list of floats in python which look like this

```
[3.09312635991831, 2.685707263863166, 1.7249614343269735, 2.551923173039131, 2.3768648392514904]
```

and plug them into a function handle but I cant seem to iterate over the list of floats. I get the error 'float' object is not iterable.
Here is what I am currently working with. Where `xpoint` and `ypoint` are the lists of floats and `func` is the expression `func = lambda x,y: x**2 + y**2`.

```
def monte_carlo_integral(a,b,c,n,func):
    T = triangle_area(a, b, c)
    left = T*(1/n)
    points = random_numbers(a, b, c, n, 1)
    xpoint = [item[0] for item in points]
    ypoint = [item[1] for item in points]
    for i in range(n):
        right = sum(func(xpoint[i],ypoint[i]))
    print(right)
```

I reproduced the problem here.

```
func = lambda x,y: x**2 + y**2
x = [2.9326170613860096, 1.8654993478646646, 2.878679040963291, 1.2534822780679544, 2.9724667148405075]
y = [3.7757464252380686, 1.1428831196926126, 2.107894507044161, 1.8353208404114492, 3.868876505529935]
for i in range(5):
    summation = sum(func(x[i],y[i]))
    
print(summation)
```

Comment: _but I cant seem to iterate over the list of floats_ What do you mean you can't?  What happens when you try?  Do you get an error?

Comment: Yes I get the error 'float' object is not iterable. sorry will edit

Comment: Please share a [mre].

Comment: That seems to indicate that somewhere you think you have a list of floats but you, in fact, only have a single float object, not a list. Try pdb or just some print statements. Adding a comment to the code you posted indicating which line has the problem would help.

Comment: I posted an example that gives me the same error, I basically want to iterate through all points of those two lists in my function and then summing those values up.

Comment: I guess your error comes from the `sum(func())` part, where `func()` already add up the floats returning one float and `sum(float)` raise error. Therefore, just remove the `sum()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
func = lambda x,y: x**2 + y**2
for i in range(5):
    summation = sum(func(x[i],y[i]))
```

Your problem is that `func(x[i],y[i])` returns a single float. You then try to call `sum` on this singular float.

What you probably want instead is this:

```
func = lambda x,y: x**2 + y**2
summation = 0
for i in range(5):
    summation += func(x[i],y[i])
```

Or even better, this:

```
func = lambda x,y: x**2 + y**2
summation = sum(func(x[i],y[i]) for i in range(5))
```

Or even better, this:

```
summation = sum(xi**2 + yi**2 for xi, yi in zip(x, y))
```

Also note the `math.hypot` function.

Answer (score 1):

The problem I think is in this line

```py
right = sum(func(xpoint[i],ypoint[i]))
```

the argument of the function `sum` must be an iterable object, but you're
passing a `float`. Remember that `ight = sum(func(xpoint[i],ypoint[i]))` returns
the sum of  the squares the two coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want one of the two solutions Here

Setup:

```
func = lambda x,y: x**2 + y**2
x = [2.9326170613860096, 1.8654993478646646, 2.878679040963291, 1.2534822780679544, 
2.9724667148405075]
y = [3.7757464252380686, 1.1428831196926126, 2.107894507044161, 1.8353208404114492, 
3.868876505529935]
```

Solution One:

```
summation = 0
for i in range(5):
    summation += func(x[i],y[i])
```

Solution Two :

```
summation = sum((func(x[i],y[i]) for i in range(5)))
```

Print result:

```
print(summation)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return

> x**2

and

> y**2

which you can them sum as follows:

```
func = lambda x,y: ((x**2),(y**2))
x = [2.9326170613860096, 1.8654993478646646, 2.878679040963291, 1.2534822780679544, 2.9724667148405075]
y = [3.7757464252380686, 1.1428831196926126, 2.107894507044161, 1.8353208404114492, 3.868876505529935]
for a,b in zip(x,y):
    summation += sum(func(a,b))
    
print(summation) # 92.91993379273195
```

Answer (score 0):

use the map function

```
 func = lambda x,y: x**2 + y**2
 x = [2.9326170613860096, 1.8654993478646646, 2.878679040963291, 
 1.2534822780679544, 
 2.9724667148405075]
 y = [3.7757464252380686, 1.1428831196926126, 2.107894507044161, 
 1.8353208404114492, 
 3.868876505529935]

print(list(map(func,x,y)))
```

output:

```
[22.856503896430368, 4.786269642161807, 12.73001227370828, 4.9396204086790165, 23.80376378587624]
```